# jQuery - sequence of page load(?) issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

**EDIT:**

Fixed as follows, simply hide the iframe by setting height and width to zero:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="frm" height="0" width="0"></iframe>

var frmurl ='http://www.bbc.co.uk';

jQuery(function($){
        $('#frm').attr('src', frmurl);
        var doc = $('#frm')[0].contentDocument;
        $(doc.body).html('This text should replace the BBC website');  
});
```

My website relies on a third party system to update a record in a database and display a confirmation message. Access to the third party system is via an iFrame. I would like to replace the confirmation message with one of my own.

I use jQuery and I have the iFrame working correctly except that my replacement text is displayed very briefly before the confirmation message generated by the third party system overwrites it. You can see an example [at this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HAWv8/).

How can I ensure that my own text isn't overwritten? I think it has to do with the sequence of events in which the page is generated?

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="frm" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>

var frmurl ='http://www.bbc.co.uk';

jQuery(function($){
        $('#frm').attr('src', frmurl);
        var doc = $('#frm')[0].contentDocument;
        $(doc.body).html('This text should replace the BBC website');   
});
```

Comment: If you set the "src" property of the `<iframe>` element, the browser is going to (correctly) interpret that as meaning that you want it to fetch content from that URL and display it in the frame. You could put your message somewhere else, of course, and hide the `<iframe>` if you don't want that content to be visible.

Comment: Thank you, Pointy - hiding the iframe was just what I needed to achieve my goal. Could you post your comment as an answer and I will accept it? I have edited my question to show the fix so others can benefit if they come across this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the `<iframe>` "src" property is basically an explicit request that the browser update the frame with the content fetched from the given URL. Thus, it doesn't really make sense to ask that the browser both do that and not do that :)

What you can do, however, is put your message somewhere else instead of in the `<iframe>`.  The HTTP transaction will work whether the `<iframe>` is visible or not, so if you don't want your user to see the results you can just hide the `<iframe>` via CSS or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Loading an IFRAME is asynchronous. You may be able to do what you want like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('#frm').attr('src', frmurl).load(function() {
            var doc = $(this)[0].contentDocument;
            $(doc.body).html('This text should replace the BBC website');
        });  
});
```

This waits until the IFRAME is loaded, then tries to modify it.

However, I'm not sure this will be allowed -- you're not allowed to manipulate the contents of an IFRAME loaded from a different domain.

UPDATE:

I was right, it doesn't work. I tried this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/HAWv8/1/) and the console logs:

> Blocked a frame with origin `"http://fiddle.jshell.net"` from accessing a frame with origin `"http://www.bbc.co.uk"`. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

You're not allowed to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help Barmar, this now 'fixed' (or rather, worked-around) as per Pointy's comment.